# Notify client in client server application

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

first of all, I'm rather new to socket programming to go easy on me ;).
I have a Java program that uses client-server programming to communicate between 1 or more clients and the server. So the clients can send any number of messages to the server where the messages are dealt with and all is fine so far. Now I want to notify the clients of e.g. database changes on the server side. So for example if one client changes for example table A, the other clients should also be notified about this change.
What I have so far is the following (server):

```
ExecutorService executor = null;
    try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);)
    {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(getThreadCount(5));
        while(true)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
            Runnable worker = new PCRequestMapper(clientSocket);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(executor != null)
        {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

The request mapper class then looks like this:

```
public class PCRequestMapper implements Runnable
{

private Socket client = null;

private static Map<Integer, PCRequestData> requestData = null;

public PCRequestMapper(Socket client)
{
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            client.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    client.getOutputStream());)
    {
        System.out.println("Thread started in PCRequestHandler with name: "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Object recObj = in.readObject();
        // ToDo Do something
        PCBaseRequest req = (PCBaseRequest) recObj;
        System.out.println("Req type: " + req.getRequestType() + " name: "
                + req.getName());

        PCRequestData data = requestData.get(req.getRequestType());
        if(data == null)
        {
            PCException ex = new PCException();
            ex.setStackTrace(new Throwable().getStackTrace());

            PCBaseReply reply = getErrorReply("No mapped request handler found in services.xml for request: "+req.getRequestType()+" - "+req.getName(), 
                    PCException.NO_MAPPED_HANDLER, ex);

            writer.writeObject(reply);
        }
        else
        {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(data.getMappedClass());
            Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor();
            PCIRequestHandler object = (PCIRequestHandler)cons.newInstance();
            PCBaseReply reply = object.heyHo(req);

            System.out.println("Writing reply: "+reply.getClass());

            writer.writeObject(reply);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
    {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It basically takes a message (request), maps it to a configured class and then that class performs whatever action needed.

On the client side, I have a class called RequestSender, which is used to send arbitrary requests to the server:

```
public class PCRequestSender
{

private static int getPort(int defaultPort)
{
    final String port = PCConfigHandler.getStringProperty("serverPort");
    if (null != port)
    {
        try
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(port);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Value of port property"
                    + " is not a valid positive integer [" + port + "]."
                    + " Reverting to default [" + defaultPort + "].");
        }
    }
    return defaultPort;
}

public static PCBaseReply sendRequest(PCBaseRequest req)
{
    PCBaseReply reply = null;
    int port = getPort(8081);
    String address = PCConfigHandler.getStringProperty("serverAddress");
    try (Socket serverSocket = new Socket(address, port);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    serverSocket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    serverSocket.getInputStream());)
    {
        out.writeObject(req);
        Object recObj = in.readObject();

        reply = (PCBaseReply) recObj;
        System.out.println("Reply: "+reply);

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return reply;
}

}
```

Now I'm a bit at a loss, because I would also like to constantly listen to a server socket to catch notifications. Do I need another socket on the server side? Is my setup not tooooo ideal?
I'm helpful for any hints...thanks!

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing ? Please can you elaborate ?

Comment: If you don't have a specific question, and just want your code to be reviewed, please submit your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My problem is that currently there is a class used to send and receive messages in a static way, but I also need a class to only listen for notifications. So if I open a socket to listen, then communication is blocked. Therefore my question is, does it make sense to open a second port on the server side only for notifications or is there a better way to achieve this